# Programmatically access selected Chart Colors on Picklist Values

Tags: visualforce, picklist, metadata

Is there a way to find out, programmatically, if my users have selected chart colors for a picklist value?  I'd like to write VisualForce (ideally in CSS, but anything is fine) that is consistent with their selected colors.

Comment: As per Salesforce this is note yet available. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kmtSAAQ

Comment: So I'd have to use the Metadata API if I wanted to do that?  likely not worthwhile...